# Coverting a hibernate Query List into a HashMap in the shortest possible way.Using Java 7

Tags: java, hibernate

There are 100k+ records. I want to convert my column1, column2 in a HashMap. Later sending .toString() in a robust way.

Desired result is a string: [col1=val1 ,col2=val2,......]

Is there is a way to directly convert it into String?

```
String queryString="SELECT distinct c.billing_account_no,concat(p.eligibility_id, c.seq_id) AS full_name FROM Siebel_promo_prod_offer_fed p , ppm_offerability_account_info c WHERE p.corp_code='"+corpCode+"' and p.ELIGIBILITY_ID='"+ruleId+"'";  //System.out.println(queryString);      
List<List<Object>> accountIDs= session.createSQLQuery(queryString).setResultTransformer(Transformers.TO_LIST).list();       //System.out.println("After query....");
for(List<Object> x: accountIDs){ 
    map.put((String)x.get(0),(String)x.get(1));         
}
```

I am using Java 7 technology.

Comment: are you going to return your map in a rest controller?

Comment: yes,i gonna return

Comment: I hope this will be a paginated request.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you change your ResultTransformer to Transformers.aliasToBean(MyDto.class):

```
String queryString = "SELECT distinct c.billing_account_no AS billingAccount, concat(p.eligibility_id, c.seq_id) AS fullName FROM Siebel_promo_prod_offer_fed p , ppm_offerability_account_info c WHERE p.corp_code = :corpCode and p.ELIGIBILITY_ID = :ruleId;

List<MyDto> accountIDs = session.createSQLQuery(queryString)
                .setString("corpCode", corpCode) // correct way to add params 
                .setString("ruleI", ruleId)      // correct way to add params
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyDto.class))
                .list();

for(MyDto myDto: accountIDs){
    map.put(myDto.getBillingAccount(), dto.getFullName());
}
```

**Transformers.aliasToBean** will transform your query rows into a POJO. Notice the name of the result column('AS billingAccount', 'AS fullName') name and the class attributes ('billingAccount', 'fullName'), they have the same name.

```
class MyDto {

private String billingAccount;
private String fullName;

public MyDto() {

}

public String getBillingAccount() {
    return billingAccount;
}

public void setBillingAccount(String billingAccount) {
    this.billingAccount = billingAccount;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return billingAccount + "=" + fullName;
}
}
```

calling accountIDs.toString(); you will have the desired string. You Already have the simplest way to transform List to Map.

NOTE: DO NOT USE CONCATENATION IN YOUR QUERIES, SQL INJECTIONS CAN BE EXECUTED.

PD: why not return the accountIDs?